# Centering 100% width SVG within div without slicing off top and bottom

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm looking for a way to have a inline SVG placed centered in a container div with the SVG having 100% width. I then want the top and bottom parts of the SVG to show outside of the container without those parts being sliced by the container's edges.

To illustrate what I mean, here's a simple sketch:
[image]
I've added `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"` to the SVG that lets me center the SVG within the container. I have the following CSS/HTML to the elements:

```
<div class="container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Lager_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 1000 595.3"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
    ...
    </svg>
</div> 


.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

svg {
    width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

But that slices of the parts of the SVG falling out of the viewport or div. Is there any way to have the SVG with 100% width and then preserve the remaining top and bottom parts of the SVG, placing them outside of the div?

I want to implement this to a vertical slideshow with distance added between each slide, so when the user goes to the next slide, the SVG's top part should be visible during the transition before having the next slide centered within the viewport, like this:

[image]

Comment: Include your code...

Comment: You mean the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help with this and was able to achieve what I was looking for by adding `overflow:visible;` to the SVG:

```css
svg {
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to mark your own answer as correct? (not sure of the rule.) do it if you can.

Comment: In 2 days I can. :)